# Object Based EventListener/EventEmitter in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

I suddenly realized that event emitter in NodeJS is usually like a static method in Java.. Example:

```
// This illustrated that event listener is universal
function A(a){
  var that = this;
  this.a = a;
  this.cnt = 0;
  this.done = function(){
    this.emit("done");
  };
  this.say = function(){
    console.log(a + " = " + that.cnt);
  };
  this.inc = function(){
    that.cnt++;
  };
}
A.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;


var a = new A("a"),
    b = new A("b"),
    c = new A("c");

a.on("done",function(){a.inc()});
b.on("done",function(){b.inc()});
c.on("done",function(){c.inc()});


c.done();
c.done();
a.say();
b.say();
```

This code would give output:

```
a = 2
b = 2
```

While I'm actually expecting:

```
a = 0
b = 0
```

I believe this is because of the line:

```
A.prototype = new events.EventEmitter;
```

and I think the "prototype" kind of definition would be used like "static" in Java.

In order to have per-object based event listener, I changed the above code to be:

```
function B(a){
  var that = this;
  this.evt = new events.EventEmitter;
  this.a = a;
  this.cnt = 0;
  this.done = function(){
    this.evt.emit("done");
  };
  this.say = function(){
    console.log(a + " = " + that.cnt);
  };
  this.inc = function(){
    that.cnt++;
  };
}

var a = new B("a"),
    b = new B("b"),
    c = new B("c");

a.evt.on("done",function(){a.inc()});
b.evt.on("done",function(){b.inc()});
c.evt.on("done",function(){c.inc()});

c.done();
c.done();
a.say();
b.say();
```

This would be per-object event listener, but I don't really think that is a good design/implementation because it breaks the chaining of EventEmitter. I.e., like code bellow:

```
// can chain another method of A after the on() method
a.on("event",functionCallback).anotherMethodOfA();
```

I'd like to ask, what's a proper implementation of the per-object event listener in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addListener` or `on` to attach listeners to your custom events. You won't need to chain calls on these methods. Of course you can inherit any object from `EventEmitter` and add emitting functionality to your object. You can inherit your object from an instance of `EventEmitter`. There's is function called `inherit` in the `util` library which does that for you.

```
var util = require('util');
var eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

// Now create your constructor/object.
function MyObj(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    .
    .
    .
}
util.inherits(MyObj,eventEmitter);

// Implement your methods and add the functionality you need.
MyObj.prototype.aMethod = function(arg) {
    .
    .
    .
    // Define how to emit events
    if (arg == 'A')
        this.emit('eventA', this.a);
    else if (arg == 'B')
        this.emit('eventB');

    // Return this for chaining method calls
    return this;
}

MyObj.prototype.anotherMethod = function() {
    // Add more functionality...
    .
    .
    .
    return this;
}

// Now instantiate the constructor and add listenters

var instanceOfMyObj = new MyObj('a parameter', 'another parameter');

instanceOfMyObj.on('eventA', function(a){
    // Handle the event
});

// Now chain calls..
instanceOfMyObj.aMethod('A').anotherMethod(); // This will trigger eventA...
```